# Taking counts by specific conditions in multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

The below df shows individual observations of fish along transects. Fish family was recorded along with its length and its biomass. I would like to first create a new column which shows the number of observations over biomass 2.5 grams for the given family in each particular row at the given transect (I'm aware there are mulptiple observations for families at each transect in some cases which should give repeated values in many rows).

This is what the first 8 rows looks like:

```
ID                     Family             Length.mm. Biomass.g.
1   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      27.29      0.438
2   2019_Tela_AD_1_10     Haemulidae      51.84      2.713
3   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      54.38      3.127
4   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      54.65      2.417
5   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      55.46      2.532
6   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      55.46      2.532
7   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      55.46      2.532
8   2019_Tela_AD_1_10  Pomacentridae      55.46      2.532
```

I've previously used

```
`ave(Fish$ID, Fish[,c("ID","Family")], FUN=length)`
```

to obtain counts by Family but am not sure how to incorporate the biomass condition.

'ID' is an indicator of transect (only the first transect is shown above - there are lots more!).

I'll then turn that into a wider table (without biomass or length columns) with each column being a family and the table just containing ID and counts for each family column.

If interested, here is the dput of the first 100 rows:

```
structure(list(ID = c("2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10"), Family = c("Pomacentridae", 
"Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Serranidae", "Serranidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Acanthuridae", "Haemulidae", "Haemulidae", "Haemulidae", "Scaridae", 
"Carangidae", "Scaridae", "Labridae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", 
"Haemulidae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", 
"Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Haemulidae", 
"Lutjanidae", "Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacanthidae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Labridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Labridae", "Chaetodontidae", "Haemulidae", 
"Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Labridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae"), Length.mm. = c(27.29, 51.84, 
54.38, 54.65, 55.46, 55.46, 55.46, 55.46, 59.6, 72.06, 74.9, 
74.9, 74.9, 75.2, 75.51, 76.51, 79.31, 80, 80, 84.66, 86.02, 
86.4, 100, 108.62, 110.77, 127.25, 127.61, 134.12, 145.45, 147.45, 
166.56, 191.05, 197.06, 211.48, 220.37, 266.71, 350, 350, 364.09, 
406, 520, 22.06, 37.22, 37.75, 46.52, 47.58, 52.24, 52.32, 53.86, 
57.5, 62.28, 63.14, 65.06, 70.2, 70.55, 73.86, 75.35, 79.82, 
81.63, 109.64, 120.57, 124, 144.68, 165.7, 223.12, 290.51, 16.51, 
30.75, 32.32, 37.66, 40.63, 43.08, 44.37, 45.34, 45.71, 47.42, 
48.77, 49.97, 50.45, 52.23, 54.05, 55.46, 57.74, 61.47, 69.08, 
74.49, 74.9, 74.9, 77.17, 77.56, 79.34, 80.62, 86.08, 92.24, 
94.43, 97.6, 98.17, 100, 100, 100), Biomass.g. = c(0.438, 2.713, 
3.127, 2.417, 2.532, 2.532, 2.532, 2.532, 4.164, 5.778, 8.517, 
8.517, 8.517, 8.625, 6.696, 9.103, 10.185, 8.481, 8.481, 12.496, 
10.099, 13.319, 16.232, 23.651, 39.36, 38.525, 35.431, 45.301, 
92.096, 64.373, 55.903, 168.912, 186.322, 141.371, 99.718, 338.696, 
542.347, 814.991, 694.545, 1838.5, 1973.521, 0.177, 0.872, 0.911, 
1.481, 1.562, 2.757, 2.77, 3.033, 3.29, 4.259, 4.99, 5.48, 6.159, 
6.256, 8.152, 8.676, 8.95, 11.146, 28.07, 29.292, 41.257, 66.861, 
107.605, 173.794, 441.892, 0.056, 0.525, 1.223, 0.747, 1.255, 
1.508, 1.253, 1.342, 0.755, 1.546, 2.223, 2.161, 2.472, 2.755, 
3.068, 2.532, 3.771, 4.588, 5.058, 8.372, 8.517, 8.517, 9.349, 
7.285, 4.491, 18.362, 12.047, 14.559, 17.589, 8.216, 19.859, 
16.232, 16.232, 16.232)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
Fish  %>% 
    group_by(Family)  %>% 
    mutate(
        heavy = ifelse(`Biomass.g.` > 2.5, TRUE, FALSE),
        n_heavy = sum(heavy)
    )


# A tibble: 100 x 6
# # Groups:   Family [10]
#    ID                Family        Length.mm. Biomass.g. heavy n_heavy
#    <chr>             <chr>              <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl>   <int>
#  1 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       27.3      0.438 FALSE      53
#  2 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Haemulidae          51.8      2.71  TRUE       10
#  3 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       54.4      3.13  TRUE       53
#  4 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       54.6      2.42  FALSE      53
#  5 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       55.5      2.53  TRUE       53
#  6 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       55.5      2.53  TRUE       53
#  7 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       55.5      2.53  TRUE       53
#  8 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       55.5      2.53  TRUE       53
#  9 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       59.6      4.16  TRUE       53
# 10 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 Pomacentridae       72.1      5.78  TRUE       53
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Family) %>% 
  summarize(ct = sum(Biomass.g.>2.5)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Family, values_from = ct)
```

Output:

```
  ID                Acanthuridae Carangidae Haemulidae Labridae Pomacentridae Scaridae Serranidae Lutjanidae Chaetodontidae Pomacanthidae
  <chr>                    <int>      <int>      <int>    <int>         <int>    <int>      <int>      <int>          <int>         <int>
1 2019_Tela_AD_1_10            1          1          6        1            23        5          2         NA             NA            NA
2 2019_Tela_AD_2_10           NA         NA          2       NA            14        3         NA          1             NA            NA
3 2019_Tela_AD_3_10           NA         NA          2        2            16       NA         NA         NA              1             0
```

If you wanted to collapse over transect ID (I wasn't sure from your post, above), you could do this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Family) %>% 
  summarize(ct = sum(Biomass.g.>2.5)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Family, values_from = ct)
```

Output:

```
  Acanthuridae Carangidae Chaetodontidae Haemulidae Labridae Lutjanidae Pomacanthidae Pomacentridae Scaridae Serranidae
         <int>      <int>          <int>      <int>    <int>      <int>         <int>         <int>    <int>      <int>
1            1          1              1         10        3          1             0            53        8          2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are always many solutions to this kind of problem in R. As you are comfortable with your old code

```
ave(Fish$ID, Fish[,c("ID","Family")], FUN=length)
```

We could biuld on that and make only small changes:

```
ave(Fish$Biomass.g., Fish[,c("ID","Family")], FUN=\(x) sum(x > 2.5))
```

You used to count `Fish$ID`, now you count `Fish$Biomass.g.` after it was checked for the weight criterion. To apply that filter and count an anonymous function using `\(x)...` replaces the `length` function.
Other solutions are more flexible if you plan to add more filters but this one seems right for someone already familiar with `ave` and just one filter.